# sklearn error while n_jobs is not 1 using VScode

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to do a support vector machine with `GridSearchCV` using VScode, code as below:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
parameters = {'C':(1,10,), 'kernel': ("rbf",),'gamma':(1,10,100,1000)}
svc = SVC(probability = True)
svc_cv = GridSearchCV(svc, param_grid = parameters, refit = True, n_jobs= -1)
svc_cv.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

The problem is that when I pass the `n_jobs` that is not 1 (either `n_jobs = -1` or `2` or anyting), the error occur as :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 svc_cv.fit(x_train, y_train)

C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     71                           FutureWarning)
     72         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 73         return f(**kwargs)
     74     return inner_f
     75 

C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    693                                     verbose=self.verbose)
    694         results = {}
--> 695         with parallel:
    696             all_candidate_params = []
    697             all_out = []

C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in __enter__(self)
    709     def __enter__(self):
    710         self._managed_backend = True
--> 711         self._initialize_backend()
    712         return self
    713 

C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in _initialize_backend(self)
    719         """Build a process or thread pool and return the number of workers"""
    720         try:
--> 721             n_jobs = self._backend.configure(n_jobs=self.n_jobs, parallel=self,
    722                                              **self._backend_args)
    723             if self.timeout is not None and not self._backend.supports_timeout:

C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in configure(self, n_jobs, parallel, prefer, require, idle_worker_timeout, **memmappingexecutor_args)
    490                 SequentialBackend(nesting_level=self.nesting_level))
    491 
--> 492         self._workers = get_memmapping_executor(
    493             n_jobs, timeout=idle_worker_timeout,
    494             env=self._prepare_worker_env(n_jobs=n_jobs),

C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\joblib\executor.py in get_memmapping_executor(n_jobs, **kwargs)
     18 
     19 def get_memmapping_executor(n_jobs, **kwargs):
---> 20     return MemmappingExecutor.get_memmapping_executor(n_jobs, **kwargs)
     21 
     22 

C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\joblib\executor.py in get_memmapping_executor(cls, n_jobs, timeout, initializer, initargs, env, temp_folder, context_id, **backend_args)
     40         _executor_args = executor_args
     41 
---> 42         manager = TemporaryResourcesManager(temp_folder)
     43 
     44         # reducers access the temporary folder in which to store temporary

C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\joblib\_memmapping_reducer.py in __init__(self, temp_folder_root, context_id)
    529             # exposes exposes too many low-level details.
    530             context_id = uuid4().hex
--> 531         self.set_current_context(context_id)
    532 
    533     def set_current_context(self, context_id):

C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\joblib\_memmapping_reducer.py in set_current_context(self, context_id)
    533     def set_current_context(self, context_id):
    534         self._current_context_id = context_id
--> 535         self.register_new_context(context_id)
    536 
    537     def register_new_context(self, context_id):

C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\joblib\_memmapping_reducer.py in register_new_context(self, context_id)
    558                 new_folder_name, self._temp_folder_root
    559             )
--> 560             self.register_folder_finalizer(new_folder_path, context_id)
    561             self._cached_temp_folders[context_id] = new_folder_path
    562 

C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\joblib\_memmapping_reducer.py in register_folder_finalizer(self, pool_subfolder, context_id)
    588         # semaphores and pipes
    589         pool_module_name = whichmodule(delete_folder, 'delete_folder')
--> 590         resource_tracker.register(pool_subfolder, "folder")
    591 
    592         def _cleanup():

C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\loky\backend\resource_tracker.py in register(self, name, rtype)
    189         '''Register a named resource, and increment its refcount.'''
    190         self.ensure_running()
--> 191         self._send('REGISTER', name, rtype)
    192 
    193     def unregister(self, name, rtype):

C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\loky\backend\resource_tracker.py in _send(self, cmd, name, rtype)
    202 
    203     def _send(self, cmd, name, rtype):
--> 204         msg = '{0}:{1}:{2}\n'.format(cmd, name, rtype).encode('ascii')
    205         if len(name) > 512:
    206             # posix guarantees that writes to a pipe of less than PIPE_BUF

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 18-19: ordinal not in range(128)
```

However, I can run it perfectly normal with `n_jobs = -1` using browser-based jupyter notebook, wondering what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like if you specify running with more than one job, sklearn will try to spawn more processes. When it does this it triggers an error with what it's sending over the pipe to the process because it isn't ASCII. I would make sure that whatever sklearn might need to be sending is pure ASCII (whatever is being used to make `msg`).